# Which port is utilized by a Blue Prism process when it is ran through Process Studio?

Tags: blueprism

By default a runtime resource with 8181 port is available for the Blue Prism process to run on it but when we run in process studio without assigning a runtime resource, which port is utilized?

Comment: There is no "port" involved when running a process from the Process Studio. No communication is required to transmit the instructions over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port comes into picture only when there is movement of traffic from one system to another. When we are running a process from process studio in the local machine, then there is no need of setting up app server and hence no need of setting up resource pc and ultimately no need of port number as well.

But when we have a dedicated app server, then in order to communicate with the app server, we have to establish the connection using a specific port from where the transmission of traffic takes place. In such scenarios, we can define a specific port number.

Hope it clarifies your query.